# IntelliJ not downloading Maven sources for groovy project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, groovy

I find that "Download Sources" works great for all of our Java project. But I'm not getting it to work for Groovy projects - it doesn't error, we just don't get correct source showing in IntelliJ.

Is there a configuration somewhere in IntelliJ or Maven that will make this happen?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes i've seen the same thing. It doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone here figured it out. I added this to the pom (groovy source, groovy test source) and it all works now.

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>add-groovy-source</id>
              <!-- before package phase -->
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>add-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/main/groovy</source>
                 </sources>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
           <execution>
              <id>add-groovy-test-source</id>
              <!-- before package phase -->
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>add-test-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/test/groovy</source>
                 </sources>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```